# libusb crash on Android ARM device/emulator

Tags: android, java-native-interface, arm, libusb

I'm using the NDK to compile libusb (both from the prebuilt one supplied at: https://github.com/monaka/libusb-android) as well as using his changes to compile the latest available (libusb-1.0.8).  It appears to load and the initial call to "init()" does not return an error.  However, when I try to make the basic call into the library to list devices (from the sample lsusb code included in libusb) I get a crash.  Using the NDK-provided "arm-eabi-addr2line" and the address which the dump provides as the fault, I've tracked it down to being that the device listing method in libusb gets an "unknown status" from the device it finds which causes the "usbi_log()" method to be called within which the crash occurs.  The NDK tools don't give me line numbers so that's all the details I have for where the error is occurring.

libusb source repo: http://git.libusb.org/?p=libusb.git;a=summary;js=1

I am making a simple JNI call into libusb from a dead-simple Action, though I don't have any reason to think this is part of the issue.  It is a very basic .h (from javah) file and .c file which copies the action of the provided "lsubs" sample program and the Action class does nothing but make the call in the onLoad() method.

I also get a crash when running in the emulator.  Also unplugged device (a Nexus One) to disable debugging (also disabled in Applications->Development on device) and to have USB bus (theoretically) empty (of at least external physical devices) and get same crash.

Device and emulator Android version: 2.2
NDK version: r5b
ADK version: r10
Host OS: OSX

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

If you install an ssh daemon on the phone, then you can ssh into it with port forwarding and run gdbserver and connect to that from gdb on the pc.

You may want to build a command line executable test first, before hooking it up to your java app.

Comment: I'm looking to do this on stock phones/devices, no rooting, which I assume is required for sshd.  Due to this holdup I've already moved on to a gdb solution since my need was network-related anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: rooting would not be needed if you start sshd on a higher than usual (ie, unprivileged) port, but if you've already found a way to run gdb, great.